# ControlTemplate checkbox issue

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I've a checkbox controltemplate column in wpf datagrid, when I check few checkboxes and scroll, the selections get messed up.

I know its because the repeating visual component is kind of reused. But how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to the datagrid in the XAML:

`VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"`